# Ribbon handling in c# for outlook 2010

Tags: ribbon-control

I have placed my own ribbon in Outlook 2007 at a certain location. But when I run the code for outlook 2010 ribbon is not there where I want it like 2007. It has been placed at last position. Is there any solution for this?

Answer (score 1):

The Group ID's are different in Outlook 2007 and Outlook 2010. First, figure out if it's Outlook 2007 or 2010:

```
using Outlook = Microsoft.Office.Interop.Outlook;
Outlook.Application thisApp = new
Outlook.Application();
string outlookVersion = thisApp.Version;

if (outlookVersion.StartsWith("12."))
 // it's probably Outlook 2007
 // Outlook 2010 should start with "14."
```

Next, use the right ID for the version of Outlook. You can download spreadsheet with all the ID's from Microsoft at http://www.microsoft.com/download/en/details.aspx?displaylang=en&id=3582